# Using environment variable in non-server JS file (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm not exactly sure about the best practices for something like this, but I have a simple web page with an `index.html`, `style.css`, and `scripts.js` where I call the Spotify API. I also have a `server.js` where I'm running my Node.js server.

In order to call the Spotify API, I need to supply my client ID, which I'm storing as an environment variable in my `.env`. Esentially I'm making my API call from the front-end but need to get the environment variable from the back-end. Is there a way to pass the environment variable from `server.js` to `scripts.js`, or be able to access the environment variable directly from `scripts.js`, or do i need to restructure my app?

Let me know if i can provide more info!

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`);
})
```

**scripts.js**

```
...
function getAccess() {
    const responseType = 'token';
    const CLIENTID = process.end.CLIENT_ID;
    let redirect = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=${responseType}&client_id=${CLIENTID}&scope=${scopes}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
    window.location = redirect;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, I suggest you to create .env file and put all you secrets in it.
you can redirect from express itself have res.redirect('http://example.com'). You can use it to keep thing covered. It will prevent to expose your secrets.